# If you are setting out a curve of a large object and can access the centre of the curve, what formula can be used to do this

Tags: geometry

If the radius of a curve (part of a circle) is "R" and the chord length is "c" what formula can be used to calculate the offset between the centre of the chord and the circle?
This is used to set out road curves or other large objects.

Comment: Please provide more details, I find it hard to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it's not possible to put a drawing in a comment.

The centre of your chord, is it point $D$ or point $E$?

In case it's point $D$, the answer is simply $R$ (the radius of the chord).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that (using Dominique's nice drawing) you have

- The length $AD$, which you're calling $R$
- The length $CB$, which you're calling $c$

and you want to know

- The length $DE$, which you're calling the "offset"

This problem falls under the general notion of "segment of a circle," but most references I found don't tell you how to find the offset, which I'll call $e$.

If we extend the line $AD$ beyond $A$ to a point $Q$ on the opposite side of the circle, so that $QD$ is a diameter of a circle, then we have two "chords" of our circle: the one made from $QE$ and $ED$, and the one made from $CE$ and $EB$. The first chord is very large, because it's actually a diameter.

THere's a lovely little geometry theorem that says that if you have two intersecting chords, the product of the lengths of the two parts of one chord is the same as the product of the lengths of the two parts of the other chord. In our case, that means that

$$
CE \cdot EB = QE \cdot ED 
$$
Now both $CE$ and $EB$ have lengths $c/2$, and $ED$'s length is called $e$ and is what we're looking for. The length of $QE$ is $R + (R-e)$. So we get

\begin{align}
\frac{c}{2}\cdot \frac{c}{2} &= (2R - e) \cdot e \\
\frac{c^2}{4}&= 2Re - e^2 \\
e^2 - 2Re + \frac{c^2}{4}&= 0
\end{align}

That's a quadratic in the unknown $e$, and its solution is
$$
e = \frac{2R \pm \sqrt{4R^2 - c^2}}{2}
$$
This formula only makes sense if $c \le 2R$ (which is reasonable, because if $c$ is larger than $2R$, then $c$ isn't the length of any chord of a circle of radius $R$); otherwise we end up with a square root of a negative number.

But which of the two $e$-values do we want? It turns out that one of them is the length of $DE$, and the other is the length of $EQ$. The one you want is (presumably) the smaller one, i.e., it's
\begin{align}
e 
&= \frac{2R - \sqrt{4R^2 - c^2}}{2}\\
&= R - \frac{\sqrt{4R^2 - c^2}}{2}\\
&= R - \sqrt{R^2 - \left(\frac{c}{2}\right)^2}\\
\end{align}